# How to return and store different type view

Tags: swiftui

I want

- MapView change by condition
- store current MapView
- call method in current MapView

Is this possible?

---

MapViewEnvironment.swift

```
class MapViewEnvironment: ObservableObject {
  @Published var value1 = "aaa"
  @Published var currentMapCompany = "apple"
}
```

MapViewProtocol.swift

```
protocol MapViewProtocol {
  func aaa()
  func bbb()
}
```

AppleMapView.swift

```
struct AppleMapView: UIViewRepresentable, MapViewProtocol {
  func aaa() { print("AppleMapView - aaa") }

  func bbb() { print("AppleMapView - bbb") }
}
```

GoogleMapView.swift

```
struct GoogleMapView: UIViewRepresentable, MapViewProtocol {
  func aaa() { print("GoogleMapView - aaa") }

  func bbb() { print("GoogleMapView - bbb") }
}
```

CommonMapView.swift

```
struct CommonMapView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var mapViewEnvironment: MapViewEnvironment
  @State var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  @State var currentMapView: AnyView? // <-- correct?

  func choiceView() -> some View {
    switch mapViewEnvironment.currentMapCompany {
    case "apple":
      currentMapView = AnyView(AppleMapView()) // Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.

    default:
      currentMapView = AnyView(GoogleMapView())
    }
    return currentMapView
  }

  var body: some View {
    choiceView().onAppear {
      self.mapViewEnvironment.$value1
        .filter { $0 == "aaa" }
        .sink { _ in currentMapView.aaa() } // error
        .store(in: &self.cancellable)

      self.mapViewEnvironment.$value1
        .filter { $0 == "bbb" }
        .sink { _ in currentMapView.bbb() } // error
        .store(in: &self.cancellable)
    }
  }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var mapViewEnvironment: MapViewEnvironment

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      Button(action: { self.mapViewEnvironment.value1 = "aaa" }) { Text("set aaa") }
      Button(action: { self.mapViewEnvironment.value1 = "bbb" }) { Text("set bbb") }

      CommonMapView()
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Self answer.**

I found another way and change some class.

ContentView.swift

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var mapViewEnvironment: MapViewEnvironment

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button(action: { self.mapViewEnvironment.value1 = "aaa" }) { Text("set aaa") }
      Button(action: { self.mapViewEnvironment.value1 = "bbb" }) { Text("set bbb") }
      Button(action: { self.mapViewEnvironment.currentMapCompany = "apple" }) { Text("set apple") }
      Button(action: { self.mapViewEnvironment.currentMapCompany = "google" }) { Text("set google") }

      CommonMapView()
    }
  }
}
```

CommonMapView.swift

```
struct CommonMapView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var mapViewEnvironment: MapViewEnvironment

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
      if mapViewEnvironment.currentMapCompany == "apple" {
        AppleMapView()
      } else {
        GoogleMapView()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

AppleMapView.swift

```
struct AppleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
  @EnvironmentObject var mapViewEnvironment: MapViewEnvironment

  func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
    let view = MKMapView()
    view.mapType = .standard

    willAppear(context)

    return view
  }

  ...

  func makeCoordinator() -> AppleMapView.Coordinator {
    return Coordinator()
  }

  static func dismantleUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, coordinator: AppleMapView.Coordinator) {
    coordinator.cancellable.removeAll()
  }

  final class Coordinator {
    var cancellable = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  }
}

extension AppleMapView: MapViewProtocol {
  func willAppear(_ context: Context) {
    mapViewEnvironment.$value1.filter { $0 == "aaa" }.sink { _ in self.aaa() }.store(in: &context.coordinator.cancellable)
    mapViewEnvironment.$value1.filter { $0 == "bbb" }.sink { _ in self.bbb() }.store(in: &context.coordinator.cancellable)
  }

  func aaa() { print("AppleMapView - aaa") }

  func bbb() { print("AppleMapView - bbb") }
}
```